# Installing Docker on Vagrant multi-machine

Tags: docker, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I am trying to setup multiple machines using Vagrant and need Docker installed on them.
Everything works fine when using a *Vagrantfile* like :

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-18.04"
  config.vm.provision "docker"

  config.vm.define :worker1 do |w1|
    w1.vm.hostname = "worker1"
  end

  config.vm.define :worker2 do |w2|
    w2.vm.hostname = "worker2"
  end
end
```

However, I'd like to pull different images on each of those machines. When nesting the Docker provisioning step, Docker doesn't even get installed on the machines.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-18.04"

  config.vm.define :worker1 do |w1|
    w1.vm.hostname = "worker1"
    w1.vm.provision "docker" do |w1d|
      w1d.pull_images "python"
    end
  end

  config.vm.define :worker2 do |w2|
    w2.vm.hostname = "worker2"
    w2.vm.provision "docker" do |w2d|
      w2d.pull_images "openjdk"
    end
  end
end
```

I can achieve the desired result with a workaround :

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-18.04"
  config.vm.provision "docker"

  config.vm.define :worker1 do |w1|
    w1.vm.hostname = "worker1"
    w1.vm.provision :shell, inline: "docker pull python"
  end

  config.vm.define :worker2 do |w2|
    w2.vm.hostname = "worker2"
    w2.vm.provision :shell, inline: "docker pull openjdk"
  end
end
```

Any ideas as to why the recommended Docker provisioner doesn't work when nested like my second example ?

*Ubuntu 18.04* ; *Vagrant 2.2.3*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has been fixed in newer versions. I had it work with this Vagrantfile :

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"

  config.vm.define :worker1 do |w1|
    w1.vm.hostname = "worker1"
    w1.vm.provision "docker" do |w1d|
      w1d.pull_images "python"
    end
  end

  config.vm.define :worker2 do |w2|
    w2.vm.hostname = "worker2"
    w2.vm.provision "docker" do |w2d|
      w2d.pull_images "openjdk"
    end
  end
end
```

Host : 16.04.6 LTS
Vagrant : 2.2.6
VirtualBox : 6.1
(Note : for Vagrant 2.2.6 to work with new VirtualBox 6.1 I had to follow https://blogs.oracle.com/scoter/getting-vagrant-226-working-with-virtualbox-61-ga )